# Restlet Internal 500 error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, restlet, restlet-2.0

I'm building a jUnit test case for my GAE hosted service and one of the methods is having issues.

Here is the Resource interface:

```
public interface BasketItemResource  {

    @Delete
    public void removeBasketItem(String id);

    @Get
    public Representation listBasketItems();

    @Put
    public void addBasketItems(Representation items);
}
```

and here are my test cases:

```
@Test
public void testListItems() {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<BasketItem> items = null;

    JsonRepresentation jRep = null;
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<BasketItem>>(){}.getType();
    try {
        jRep = new JsonRepresentation(resource.listBasketItems());
        items = gson.fromJson(jRep.getJsonArray().toString(), collectionType);
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    assertEquals(items.size(), 5);
}

@Test
public void testAddItem() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    BasketItem b = new BasketItem();
    b.basketItemID = 123;
    b.brandName = "Pepsi";
    b.description = "Cola Beverage";
    b.upc = "123123123";

    List<BasketItem> items = new ArrayList<BasketItem>();
    items.add(b);

    JsonRepresentation jRep = null;
    try {
        jRep = new JsonRepresentation(new JSONArray(gson.toJson(items)));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    resource.addBasketItems(jRep);

    }
```

The listItems test executes fine but when I run the testAddItems() I first get this warning:

`INFO: Unable to register the helper org.restlet.client.ext.json.JsonConverter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.restlet.client.ext.json.JsonConverter
    at org.restlet.engine.util.EngineClassLoader.findClass(EngineClassLoader.java:101)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:723)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:761)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:801)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConverters(Engine.java:509)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:337)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:248)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:237)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:149)
    at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:331)
    at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:390)
    at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:355)
    at org.restlet.data.Method.<clinit>(Method.java:54)
    at org.restlet.engine.resource.AnnotationUtils.addAnnotationDescriptors(AnnotationUtils.java:82)
    at org.restlet.engine.resource.AnnotationUtils.addAnnotations(AnnotationUtils.java:132)
    at org.restlet.engine.resource.AnnotationUtils.getAnnotations(AnnotationUtils.java:231)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.wrap(ClientResource.java:1548)
    at com.tests.tests.BasketItemUploadTests.setUp(BasketItemUploadTests.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)`

followed by this stack trace at the (resource.addBasketItems(jRep);) line:

`Internal Server Error (500) - Internal Server Error
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource$1.invoke(ClientResource.java:1655)
    at $Proxy9.addBasketItems(Unknown Source)
    at com.tests.tests.BasketItemUploadTests.testAddItem(BasketItemUploadTests.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the stacktrace you posted, the class `org.restlet.client.ext.json.JsonConverter` cannot be found. Make sure the jar file that contains the class `org.restlet.client.ext.json.JsonConverter` is in your classpath at the time you run your junit test. Perhaps adding your project's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder to the classpath will resolve your problem.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I was thinking somehthing was wrong there as I had the org.restlet.ext.json.JsonConverter import working fine. That's weird that it would be looking for the org.restlet.client version, I'm using the Java SE version.

Comment: wait, that doesn't work. None of the packages have org.restlet.client.ext.json.JsonConverter

Comment: @Piers MacDonald: How are you running your JUnit test? Through an IDE such as Eclipse? Or through an Ant task?

Comment: @PiersMacDonald: You need to figure out which jar has `org.restlet.client.ext.json.JsonConverter` and add it to your Eclipse project's java build path so that JUnit can find it.

Comment: I think you will have to add org.restlet.ext.json.jar of the client distribution !